# Use of the word "state"

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder if the use of "state" in the sentence below is correct or not. What I want to learn is whether this sentence is grammatically correct or not.

> Water vapour is water’s state turned into gas form by boiling at 100 degree.

Answer (score 1):

I can't easily explain why the sentence is poor, but I would write it is as

> Water vapour is its gaseous state formed by boiling at 100 degrees.

This also avoids using the word "water" twice in proximity.

However the sentence is *scientifically* incorrect. Water vapour is created naturally from water, the process of [**evaporation**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/evaporation) - turning from liquid into vapour, such as when a puddle dries out. Boiling it simply makes it impossible for the water to remain in its liquid state.

Comment: Is use of “state” in this way incorrect?

Comment: Not entirely. The *water* has turned from liquid into gas. The water's *state* has turned from liquid to gaseous. The word "liquid" is both a noun and an adjective, but "gas" is a noun and "gaseous" the adjective.

Comment: If i use sentence like ; Water’s state turned into gas form by boiling at 100 degree is called vaporization. Would it be correct ?

Comment: "Degrees" needs to be in the plural.

Comment: I got it. Is use of state correct here? I am asking it because i realy need it to solve problem.

Comment: As I tried to say: it is the water that changed to gas. Its state turned to gaseous. I have written in the answer how I would say it.

Comment: 'Water's state' is _either_ solid, liquid or vapour. All you need to say in your sentence  is 'water turned into gas form'.

Comment: You've missed *boiling **water** at 100 degrees*. Otherwise, it could be referring to boiling frogs. Or bricks. You don't want to write *water* twice, but *water vapour* is not the same thing as *water*. And maybe there would be enough distance between them in your version. (If you made that change, I'd also replace *it* with *the*.) In short: *Water vapour is **the** gaseous state formed by boiling **water** at 100 degrees.* And, to be strictly correct per your clarification, *water vapour is the gaseous **result of** boiling water at 100 degrees.*